# Return raw html as from jQuery('<div></div>'), from an unmounted react component

Tags: jquery, html, dom, reactjs

I'm using `jsPlumb` (which I'm sure is not that relevant) and at a certain point I'm making a custom overlay, which needs a `$()` html constructor:

```
create:function(component) {
    return $("<select id='myDropDown'><option value='foo'>foo</option><option   value='bar'>bar</option></select>");
}
```

I've tried to return a string, or just a React element, but that won't work.

I'm pretty sure the method just wants some raw `html` element, so it shouldn't matter if it's jQuery I use. (Like how you console it out in Chrome, it prints the html, which I'm sure is some native DOM-format?)

How do I return the **raw HTML** *from an unmounted react component?*

All I can find is how to convert HTML to a React component, which is the reverse. And I'd like to **avoid jQuery altogether**

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery object can convert to DOM object easily.
For Example.The jQuery Obj: $(selector). The DOM obj: $(selector)[0].

Answer (score 0):

If the component isn't already rendered to your DOM.  You can use `ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(component)`.  Even though its name spaced inside of ReactDOMServer it should still work.

Another possibility is to create a new DOM node, render react to it normally, then grab its content.  Maybe something like this:

```
create: function(component) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    React.render(component, div);
    return $(div.innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: Any way to avoid using jQuery?

Comment: @BlockChange just try `return div.innertHTML` then.  Beyond that I would need to see what is jsPlumb you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

`$("<div>")` will return only object. better way to do this is wrap that html into div and return the parents html

```
$("<select id='myDropDown'><option value='foo'>foo</option><option value='bar'>bar</option></select>").wrap("<div>").parent().html()
```